# Don't allow dragging two objects to empty div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I set myself the task of making some simple games for young children to do to help catch up.  I'm dragging up my old programming days.  Surprising how you much forget and how much changes!  I've been enjoying it and loved solving problems.

I've reached a point that I don't understand.

I have 10 counters that are all individual counters, contained in one div at the top of the page.
I have 10 empty div boxes to drag the counters.
I have managed to drag the counters to the empty divs.  The issue is I don't want children to be able to drag more than one counter to a box.

I found a similar problem on here and did the suggestion (that makes sense) - checking if a div has any child nodes.  If it doesn't then you can drop the counter.  If it does then it displays an error message.

However what happens now is if I drag one counter its stays in the box.  It allows me to also then drag another counter to the same box (appears to just replace the first counter).  It doesn't though allow me to drag a third counter.  When I try and do so it then displays the error.

I've tried to display on the error the number of child nodes and it only registers a child node once the second counter has been put into a div box.

Why does it allow me to drag the second counter.  It's almost like it does not recognise the first counter drag as the child.

Any help appreciated.  You'd make me happy!

```
function onDragStart(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', event.target.id);
  }

function onDragOver(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

function onDrop(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var id = event.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    
    if (event.target.hasChildNodes()) {alert("That is not possible")} else {   
        event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(id))}

    event.dataTransfer.clearData();
 
  }
```

And here is the HTML. Sorry I didn't add it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Ten Frame Example</title>
</head>
<body onload="generateRandomNumber ()">
    
    <div id = "counterStore" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event)"">
        <p>
            <img src="counter.png" id = "counterOne" height = "100" width = "100" draggable = "true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event);">
            <img src="counter.png" id = "counterTwo" height = "100" width = "100" draggable = "true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event);">
            <img src="counter.png" id = "counterThree" height = "100" width = "100" draggable = "true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event);">
            <img src="counter.png" id = "counterFour" height = "100" width = "100" draggable = "true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event);">
            <img src="counter.png" id = "counterFive" height = "100" width = "100" draggable = "true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event);">
            <img src="counter.png" id = "counterSix" height = "100" width = "100" draggable = "true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event);">
            <img src="counter.png" id = "counterSeven" height = "100" width = "100" draggable = "true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event);">
            <img src="counter.png" id = "counterEight" height = "100" width = "100" draggable = "true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event);">
            <img src="counter.png" id = "counterNine" height = "100" width = "100" draggable = "true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event);">
            <img src="counter.png" id = "counterTen" height = "100" width = "100" draggable = "true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event);">
      </p>
    </div>

    <p> <h1>Drag <span id="myRandomNumber"></span> counters to the ten frame</h1></p>
    
    <div class="divTable tenFrame">
        <div class="divTableBody">
            <div class="divTableRow">
                <div class="divTableCell" id = "cellOne" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event);"></div><div class="divTableCell" id = "cellTwo" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event);"></div><div class="divTableCell" id = "cellThree" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event);"></div><div class="divTableCell" id = "cellFour" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event);"></div><div class="divTableCell" id = "cellFive" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event);"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="divTableRow">
                <div class="divTableCell" id = "cellSix" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event);"></div><div class="divTableCell" id = "cellSeven" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event);"></div><div class="divTableCell" id = "cellEight" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event);"></div><div class="divTableCell" id = "cellNine" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event);"></div><div class="divTableCell" id = "cellTen" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event);"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFindTotal()">Click to check if you are correct</button>

    <div id ="Results">
        This is where the result will be displayed
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS - thinking the issues must be in here.  I copied it from one of those html generators.

```
div.tenFrame {
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 600px;
    height: 240px;
    text-align: left;
    
    
    
  }
  .divTable.tenFrame .divTableCell, .divTable.tenFrame .divTableHead {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 20%;
    height: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

  .tenFrame.outerTableFooter .tableFootStyle {
    padding: 3px 5px; 
  }
  .divTable{ display: table; }
  .divTableRow { display: table-row; }
  .divTableHeading { display: table-header-group;}
  .divTableCell, .divTableHead { display: table-cell;}
  .divTableHeading { display: table-header-group;}
  .divTableFoot { display: table-footer-group;}
  .divTableBody { display: table-row-group;}

  #counterStore {
      background-color: gray;
      width: 550px;
      height: 250px;
      position: relative;
    }
```

Comment: Hey pencho, welcome to StackOverflow. Is it possible that you could provide the HTML also? We need a working example in order to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thank you Tom.  I've learnt so much from people on here, reading the responses.  I just can't seem to fathom this out.  Fingers crossed someone can help.  Pencho

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting the HTML.

There were a few issues with the HTML you posted:

- The `counterstore` div had two closing speech marks on the onDrop event:
   `ondrop="onDrop(event)""`
- You also can't have an `h1` tag inside a `p` tag. It may work in some browsers but it's invalid.
- In the onDrop handler, you weren't filtering by ID and you weren't checking for the relevant nodeType

After fixing these issues, I couldn't reproduce the problem you had.

Here's a jsFiddle showing it working: https://jsfiddle.net/odL19462/

I would highly recommend using an IDE to develop! It would have detected these issues. I prefer PHPStorm but there are free alternatives like VSCode.

(I added some styles because there was no css. I also implemented dragging them back into the store).

Comment: **medit** is a nice code editor too, it is available for Linux.

Comment: Hi Tom.  Thank you so much.  This has helped me understand better. However for some reason mine still makes the same mistake.  Could it be the CSS?  I have included it above.I know I am being a pest and asking a lot, it's driving me insane to fix.  What you have here works perfectly - I don't know why it doesn't on mine.  I am using VSCode - not sure why it didn't pick up the issues.

Comment: Hi Tom, Sorry please just ignore me, it does work.  For some reason on my CSS my counter store wasn't big enough, so it looked like it was overlapping the cell.  This looks brilliant.  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Hi Tom,  Can i be cheeky and ask is there an easy way to get the counters in the store to all overlap. So they are on top of each other. There is still 10, but they just are stored on top of each other like you've got a pile. Thank you so much, you have helped massively this evening.

Comment: "For some reason on my CSS my counter store wasn't big enough, so it looked like it was overlapping the cell" - this is why it's important that you post complete code when you have an issue :)

If you want the counters to overlap, just set `position: absolute` in the css

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@TomMettam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1872867/tom-mettam)'s answer, I recommend checking out [jQuery](https://jquery.com), which makes working with HTML much easier and is a standard tool for web development.

Comment: (Opinion) Please don't. It's time for jQuery to die. Use a truly powerful framework like react or angular - jQuery just results in convoluted, messy code.

Comment: @TomMettam Yeah, but would you recommend React or Angular to a beginner? Those are heavy (at least React, I haven't used Angular). For the tasks in the OP's question jQuery makes it much easier than using plain JS.